# If $p_n$ is the $n$th positive term of conditionally convergent $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$, then what's $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ be **conditionally** convergent.

If $p_n$ is the $n$th positive term of convergent $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$, then what's $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k$?

Is it only the positive terms or all terms starting from $p_n$?

Similar question, if $q_n$ was the $n$th negative term.

---

Specifically I'm asked to prove the divergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k$. But I don't understand what $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k$ is.

Comment: Do you mean that $p_n$ is the $n$-th positive term of the sequence $b_h:=\sum_{k=1}^ha_k$, where $b_h$ is convergent ?

Comment: Uff... So childish. I wish you the best.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli What I've written is what (and all) my assignment says.

Comment: I don't care who wrote it. I care of my doubt being cleared.

Comment: No definite answer: If $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ then the sum of $\sum p_n$ diverges while $\sum a_n$ converges. If $a_n$ is already positive then $p_n=a_n$ and $\sum p_n$ converges

Comment: If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k$ is the sum of positive terms only, then the proof would follow directly from the definition of conditional convergence. But the above assignment is a bit unclear on, whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p_k$ is the sum of only positive terms.